# Git Archive but first put all the files inside a folder then start archiving

Tags: wordpress, git, archive

As title suggest, I want to know if there is a single git command that put all my project in one folder first (not including .gitignored files) and then proceed archiving the folder— leaving ignored files not included when archiving which is nice.

This can be beneficial for me as I am working on WordPress plugin with multiple release. Some [references](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive).

Comment: Is your project already in a git repo? `git archives` archive a repo as is (not included any .gitignored file). It doesn't move anything first.

Comment: yes already in a repo. Essentially, I want all the files (minus the .gitignored files) move to a folder first then proceed archiving that folder. I am not sure if that is doable. @VonC I have edited my question to be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want all the files (minus the `.gitignored` files) move to a folder first then proceed archiving that folder

It is possible in one command provided you define an alias but this isn't git-related:
you can:

- clone your repo elsewhere (that way you don't get any ignored or private file)
- move your files as you see fit in that local clone
- archive (`tar cpvf yourArchive.tar yourFolder`)

But [`git archive`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) alone won't help you move those files, which is why I would recommend a script with custom bash commands (not git commands).

Comment: Thanks for the general idea. I will mark this as answered.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to copy / clone the repo anywhere.

1. Make sure you committed all your changes.
2. Process the files any way you want.
3. Run `tar -cvjf dist/archive-name.tbz2 --transform='s,^,archive-name/,' $(git ls-tree --full-tree -r --name-only --full-name HEAD)`
4. run `git reset --hard` to restore without any of the changes you made in step #2.

Hints:

- The `--transform='s,^,archive-name/,' is so your files will be extracted to`archive-name/....`, you can remove it if you don't need that.

Comment: Good implementation of what I proposed. I would still prefer to do that in a clone, that way I don't have to touch/reset anything in my current working repo. +1

Comment: True, but with your approach you'd have to manually delete / remove the .git folder.

Comment: Agreed, the git ls-tree is well used here. Good answer.

Comment: If the name list blows command-line limits, GNU tar can read paths from stdin with `-T -`.